# Command cd behavior

Tags: bash, cd-command

Since ubuntu 17.10, my scripts don't work the same way they used to do:

```
cd a*
```

would change directory to the first directory beginning with `a`.
Now, I get this error:

```
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

I guess it now detects multiple arguments due to the multiple directories beginning with `a` and throws an error.
How could I change the behavior of `cd` to the old way?

Comment: Interesting. Never new in 16.04 I could type `cd D*` and it changes to `~/Desktop`.

Comment: It was already reported to the [launchpad as bug 1683576](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/1683576): steps to reproduce, expected and actual behavior needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the same question: [Ubuntu 17.04 — bash: cd: too many arguments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905832/ubuntu-17-04-bash-cd-too-many-arguments). Apparently it is a bug.

The workaround proposed there is to create a function, based on the builtin `cd` command that overrides its behaviour:

```
cd(){ builtin cd "${@:1:1}"; }
```

Place the above line into the beginning of your script and then use `cd a*` as in Ubuntu 16.04. Use `export -f cd` if you want to use it in a sub shell.

You could define and export the function also in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
cd(){ builtin cd "${@:1:1}"; }
export -f cd
```

Comment: Since you already marked the Q as a duplicate, why bother duplicating the accepted answer from the duplicate Q?

Comment: @Xen2050, it was hard decision :) because sometimes it is easy to find the essential part of the answer under the question that is marked as duplication. Also these `export` things are not clarified under the original answer.

Comment: I didn't notice the export, but that does help. I'd have thought "for the rep", but either way here's +10

Answer (score 8):

This looks like a bug in Bash: per `man builtins` the old behaviour is the correct one.

```
   cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]
              Change the current directory to dir.  if dir is not supplied,
              the  value  of  the  HOME shell variable is the default.  Any
              additional arguments following dir are ignored.
```

You can report the bug on the `bug-bash` mailing list; more details [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

---

Actually, the bug was reported (long ago). If you want a fixed Bash now, now, *now*, here's how to do it properly (tested on 17.10, should work on others as well).

First create a directory to work in, for example:

```
mkdir ~/bash
cd ~/bash
```

Get the source package and the build dependencies:

```
apt-get source bash
sudo apt-get build-dep bash
cd bash-4.4
```

Edit `config-top.h` to change this (should be line 32)

```
#define CD_COMPLAINS
```

to this

```
/* #define CD_COMPLAINS */
```

Edit `debian/changelog` and add an entry like this at the top (you can also use the command `dch -i`):

```
bash (4.4-5ubuntu1+cd) artful; urgency=medium

  * Fix cd.

 -- Firas Kraiem <firas@fkraiem.org>  Thu, 04 Jan 2018 21:11:22 +0900
```

The most important points are to append `+foo` to the ***current*** version number (`foo` can be any string of lowercase letters; and be careful if you use `dch -i`, it will increment the last number, so you need to revert it to the current one) and to use the correct release name (`artful` here). Finally, run `dpkg-source --commit`.

You can then run the `debuild` command, and if everything goes well (errors about `debsign` can be ignored) you should have some `.deb`s in the parent directory, which you can install as usual (there is no need to install all of them, just the ones you have now; use `dpkg -l | grep bash` to find out).

Note that the version number of the new package is set so that you will automatically get any future update to `bash`; if the update does not fix the problem, you have to repeat the above process.

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate. This answer is useful and does not appear on the duplicate linked question. It may be worth adding this answer to that question, https://askubuntu.com/questions/905832/ubuntu-17-04-bash-cd-too-many-arguments

Comment: @Arronical Will do; it was closed while I was writing.