# How to get the latest PHP 7.3 patches in 18.04?

Tags: apt, upgrade, php

I have installed PHP 7.3 via the `ppa:ondrej/php` repository and everything was running smoothly, until I ran across this major 7.3.0 bug with `__callStatic` which lead to a lot of broken code in my installation.

There are merged pull requests in the PHP repo fixing this issue, however, I'm uncertain on how to get those fixes for myself now.

https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/773ed62555bc7a1d45e1ba1e11dfd99eeccbec8f

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77339

http://news.php.net/php.cvs/104021

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade php7.3
```

But it says that I'm on the latest version:

> php7.3 is already the newest version (7.3.0-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).

Help on how to get these fixes on my computer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I assume that just waiting for 7.3.1 is not an option?

Comment: @karel [The latest released PHP version is 7.3.0.](http://php.net/downloads.php)

Comment: Basically, the patches will probably be included in PHP 7.3.1, and when it is released it will probably be available on the PPA you are using. If you want a fix now, now, now, the best way would be to build new packages like what I'm doing for Bash in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/992235/256317) (I cannot post a similar answer here, as I would not be able to test it).